# Global pointer to a local variable in function

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *ptr;

void func1() {
    int a = 10;
    ptr = &a;
}

int main()
{
    func1()
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

./a.out gives 10 correctly.

In the above code, 'a' is the local variable whose scope will be within func1(). As per my understanding when the method is activated, a block of memory cells, called activation record, is allocated, which contains all local variables and formal parameters of the current method call. The activation record is used during the method execution, and is then removed at the end of the execution. When the activation record is removed, the memory locations for the local variables and for the formal parameters are destroyed and the values they contain are lost. But here, at main function when printing the value stored in the memory address of 'a' gives 10 correctly. Pl clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: it's undefined behavior.

It's true that the value of `&a` is only valid inside the function `func1`, accessing it in `main` is undefined behavior, its value maintains "valid" probably because it's still in the stack, but you shouldn't rely on undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The value of 10 at &a remains in the memory because nothing is overwrites it. If you would call an other function, you probably won't get 10 any more.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely risky. A local object/variable gets automatically released (freed) when going out of scope, so pointer of a local variable is undefined outside the scope.

```
void func1() {
    int a = 10; // local variable, goes out of scope on return from this function
    ptr = &a; // pointer of local variable is RISKY to pass, as this will be gone
}
```

If you require the value of the insider variable, pass this by value as below, for example,

```
int func1() {
    int a = 10; // local variable, goes out of scope on return from this function
    return a; // fine, as local variable will be copied to a temporary before return
}
```